# Atmel studio 7 vs Arduino IDE for register level coding?

Tags: arduino-ide, atmel-studio

Which one is better to get started with register level embedded c coding?
Also which one is used professionally?

Comment: 1) doesn't matter. 2) Arduino shouldn't be used professionally.

Answer (score 2):

I actually wouldn’t recommend either for professionally developing for Atmel chips. Although Atmel Studio is a nice enough IDE (the simulator is amazing!), it does make it *very* difficult to unit test your code or to set up a build server. I would personally recommend you set up a Make (or possibly CMake) based setup directly on top of the `avr-gcc` tool chain and then simply use the text editor of your choice.

As for learning about programming against raw registers, I have to recommend Atmel Studio and one of their XPlained evaluation boards. Atmel Studio includes a simulator that actually shows you, bit by bit, the current state of the registers.

Comment: How do you set up a Make based setup directly on top of the avr-gcc tool chain. i don't know how to go about doing it. So, it would be great if you could give some insight on how to do it.

Comment: Here’s an [avr template](https://github.com/rubberduck203/avr-template) I created and a [digital thermometer project](https://github.com/rubberduck203/digital-thermometer) I’ve been working on based on it.

Answer (score 1):

Atmel Studio for professional. Arduino is for fun and is normally the first step into embedded c programming using the atmega328 (Arduino)